# docker attach: Why can't I detach from my Docker container?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

For some reason, I can't detach from Docker containers after running `docker attach <container>`. The documentation says to use `Ctrl-p, Ctrl-q`, but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried `ctrl-q + ctrl-p` (combination, as opposed to in-sequence) and `ctrl-shift-q, ctrl-shift-p` and `ctrl-shift-q + ctrl-shift-p`. Even setting a detach key, for example `--detach-keys="p"` won't detach from the container.

Furthermore, other things don't seem to be working. For example, according to documentation, `ctrl-c` should cause the attached container to stop and detach. However, I haven't been able to get `ctrl-c` working on any of my containers. Unlike `ctrl-q`, however, `ctrl-c` renders feedback as expected, showing a `^C` in the terminal.

I've noticed that for some reason, when I press `ctrl-p`, I get a `^P` in the terminal, but pressing `ctrl-q` or `ctrl-shift-q` renders no terminal feedback.

Can anyone venture a guess as to why this might be happening?

I'm using iTerm2 on MacOS if it matters. Also, the containers in question were launched with `docker-compose`.

Edit: For clarity, I launched my container with `docker-compose up` on the following `compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: container-test
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
```

Then I attach using:

```
$ docker attach container-test
```

Edit 2: After some testing, I can confirm this issue still exists in MacOS Terminal.

Comment: How did you start your container, please include the full docker command.

Comment: Added as requested by @BMitch

Comment: I'm not sure `docker-compose` will configure the container with interactive input, and `tty` is a separate option you'd need to enable. I believe you need both of those for the detach key combination to work, but I'd need to do more testing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `--sig-proxy=false` to prevent signals being passed to container and detach using `Ctrl+C`:

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false container-test
```

---

This seems to be a known issue:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1598

Answer (score 4):

I found that by adding the following lines to my `docker-compose`, I could get it to exit and respond to inputs.

```
services:
  test:
    // etc...
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    // etc...
```